# AWS Glue is throwing error while processing data in TBs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am converting CSV data on s3 in parquet format using AWS glue ETL job. Snappy compressed parquet data is stored back to s3.

Complete Architecture: 
As data is uploaded to s3, a lambda function triggers glue ETL job if it's not already running. A job continuously uploads glue input data on s3. Glue successfully processes 100GB data but as input data piles up to 0.5 to 1TB, Glue job throws an error after running for a long time, say 10 hours.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script_2018-01-08-23-01-55.py", line 60, in <module>
partitioned_dataframe.write.partitionBy(['part_date']).format("parquet").save(output_lg_partitioned_dir, mode="append")
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1515414270379_0004/container_1515414270379_0004_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 550, in save
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1515414270379_0004/container_1515414270379_0004_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1515414270379_0004/container_1515414270379_0004_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1515414270379_0004/container_1515414270379_0004_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o193.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 3228 tasks (1024.0 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
... 30 more

End of LogType:stdout
```

I worked a lot to resolve this error but got no clue. Though I tried some suggested approach like -

```
setting SparkConf: conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g")
```

The above setting didn't work. I would appreciate it if you could provide any guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Sumit, any resolution for this problem?

Comment: Hey @vsdaking, we just divided the glue input data in multiple chunks of approx 100 GB and increased Glue job execution frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Glue default DPU count is 10 DPU, where a single Data Processing Unit (DPU) provides 4 vCPU and 16 GB of memory. Try increasing DPU count for single job run.

For your use case, I would suggest increasing the DPU count to 64. As for single run you are receiving nearly 1 TB of file. Currently by default you can use 100 DPU for individual ETL job run. [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-service-limits.html) Although you could always reach to AWS support for any of the limit increase.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc_conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", 0)
sc_conf.set("spark.executor.memory", '4g')

sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
```

that works for me, please give it a try